# Territories not auto-assigned to Opportunities upon creation

Tags: opportunity, automation, territory-management, territory

Situation :

When I create an `account`, it auto-populates the territories in account -> **works as expected** by using "Account Assignment Rules Defined in This Territory"

When I create an `opportunity` assigning that account (with >1 territories) to it, I can't get it to auto-populate the territories at `opportunity` (It has nothing assigned instead but allows me to manually populate it).

How do I **auto-assign** territory to `opportunity` using the territories assigned to `account` ?

~~**UPDATES**~~

Previous research I did:

Since [Territory Management Assignment Rules for Opportunities](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hcv2AAA) is not available in SFDC yet*,  I need to find a workaround so that I can auto assign territory to opportunity somehow. I have tried checking the [Confine Opportunity Assignment checkbox](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_territories_how_are_opportunities.htm) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, referring to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_territories_how_are_opportunities.htm

Opportunities are not automatically assigned to the same territory as the account when:
An account is reassigned to multiple territories in one operation. The account's opportunities from the original territory no longer belong to any territories, unless the Confine Opportunity Assignment checkbox is checked.

Is that your case?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I took a look at that exact page an hour ago. I tried checking the Confine Opportunity Assignment checkbox but it still didn't work. That is why I asked the question here.